# Add values to rCharts hPlot tooltip

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I would like to add some extra values to the standard Highcharts tooltip via rCharts. Example code:

```
require(rCharts)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = c(5:1), 
             z = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
             name = c("K", "L", "M", "N", "O"))
h1 <- hPlot(x = "x", y = "y", data = df, type = "scatter", group = "z")
```

This generates a tooltip with the x and y values. And the series name z as title. Now I also want the to add the name values to the tooltip. However I have no idea how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several years, I have an answer.

It seems like these wrapper functions like `hPlot()` does not support additional tooltip variables even with a simple custom formatter function. See working example below based on the dataset from the question.

```
require(rCharts)
# create data frame
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = c(5:1), 
                 z = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                 name = c("K", "L", "M", "N", "O"))

# Plot using hPlot() approach
h1 <- hPlot(x = "x", y = "y", data = df, type = "scatter", group = "z")
h1$tooltip(borderWidth=0, followPointer=TRUE, followTouchMove=TRUE, shared = FALSE,
           formatter = "#! function(){return 'X: ' + this.point.x + '<br>Y: ' + this.point.y + '<br>Z: ' + this.point.z + '<br>Name: ' + this.point.name;} !#")
h1
```

[image: hplot-rcharts]

Tooltips do not work in the above example because the variables in the array are not named. See `str(h1)`.

```
# Plot using manual build
h1 <- rCharts:::Highcharts$new()
dlev <- levels(factor(as.character(df$z)))
for(i in 1:length(dlev))
{
  h1$series(data = toJSONArray2(df[df$z==dlev[i],,drop=F], json = F,names=T), name = dlev[i],type = c("scatter"), marker = list(radius = 3))
}
h1$tooltip(borderWidth=0, followPointer=TRUE, followTouchMove=TRUE, shared = FALSE,
           formatter = "#! function(){return 'X: ' + this.point.x + '<br>Y: ' + this.point.y + '<br>Z: ' + this.point.z + '<br>Name: ' + this.point.name;} !#")
h1
```

[image: manual-build-rcharts]

This works because the array variables are named using `names=T` in the line starting `h1$series...`. See `str(h1)`.

This sort of solves the tooltip issue, but there might be other problems with the named arrays. For example, it breaks things in a shiny-app environment. There must be a reason why `hPlot()` does not use the named arrays.

Answer (score 3):

`rCharts` is a great package. But it still not well documented(Maybe I miss this point). I think you need to redefine new JS function for `tooltip` attribute. 
Any JS literals need to be wrapped between #! and !# . Here a beginning but it doesn't work as I imagine ( I think is a good start):

```
h1$tooltip( formatter = "#! function() { return 'x: '     + this.point.x + 
                                                'y: '    + this.point.y  + 
                                                'name: '  + this.point.group; } !#")
```

Comment: Indeed this is a good start. I just found the highcharts tooltip formatter documentation their site.

Comment: @jeroen81 Do you mean that there are documentation somewhere? Can you add a link to it please or add you answers if you succeed to get better results?

Comment: @agstudy: Take a look here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.tooltip

Comment: @pfuhlert ok..but can you give me more context please...It was a long time that I have answered this question...

Comment: I just tried to answer you question. There you find all options that you can use for a tooltip.

Comment: So does anyone actually have an answer on how to add `name` to the tooltip? One source points to the use of multi-dimensional arrays as series. But here, `x`, `y`, `z` etc are all passed as 1-dimensional vectors.