# rCharts Highcharts Add extra data to tooltip

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I have a dataframe with 4 columns. I use two columns (x,y) to plot for x and y. Third column (group) is used for grouping. And my fourth column (cat) is not used, but I would like it to be displayed in the tooltip.

Here is my dataframe.

```
library(rCharts)
df <- data.frame(x=c(1:12,1:12),
                 y=c(0.6, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.8, 0.99, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7, 0.6, 0.8,
                         0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.7, 0.2, 0.01, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2),
                 group=c(rep("group1",12),rep("group2",12)))

df$cat <- c(rep(c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6)),2))
```

I use `hPlot`function from `rCharts`to create the highcharts bar column plot.

```
p <- hPlot(x = "x", y = "y", data = df, type = c("column"),group="group")
p$addParams(dom = "plot1")
p$tooltip(borderWidth=0,
           headerFormat="<span style='font-size: 10px'><b>{point.key}</b></span><br/>",
           followPointer=TRUE,
           followTouchMove=TRUE,
           shared = FALSE)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514457/set-additional-data-to-highcharts-series), it explains to add the extra data to the series. Seems straight forward but I havn't been able to get it to work. I have tried all sorts of things using `toJSON` from `jsonlite` and `toJSONArray` from `RJSONIO`. But, it refuses to work. That is the first part of the problem.

The second part is to actually display the tooltip once the data is in, using formatter. The [highcharts reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) suggests:

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
                '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
        }
    }
```

How does one do this in R?

```
#idea1. maybe like this?
p$tooltip(formatter=function () {
  return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
    '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
})

#idea2. or like this?
p$tooltip(formatter="function () {
  return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
    '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
}")

#idea3. or perhaps like this?
p$tooltip(formatter=function () {
  "return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
    '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';"
})
```

Anyway, none of them work. So, if anyone has any insights, I would like to know. Thanks a lot.

PS: The same question was posted by [someone else before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086812/add-values-to-rcharts-hplot-tooltip), but doesn't have a complete answer.

Comment: https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/219

Answer (score 2):

,Hi you have to put your formatter function between "#!...!#" like this :

```
p$tooltip(formatter="#!function () {
  return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
    '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
}!#")
```

@Ramnath probably answered a similar question somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that `hPlot()` cannot be used to show additional variables in tooltips. See working example below:

```
library(rCharts)

d <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                y=c(0.7,0.8,0.7,0.3,0.5,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.5,
                    0.3,0.2,0.3,0.7,0.5,0.8,0.6,0.6,0.5,0.7),
                type=factor(c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")),
                pop=c("Group 1","Group 1","Group 1","Group 1","Group 1","Group 1","Group 2","Group 2","Group 2","Group 2",
                      "Group 1","Group 1","Group 1","Group 1","Group 1","Group 1","Group 2","Group 2","Group 2","Group 2"))

hp <- hPlot(x = "x", y = "y", data = d, type = c("column"), group = "type")
hp$plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal", pointPadding = 0, groupPadding = 0, borderWidth = 0))
hp$tooltip(borderWidth=0, followPointer=TRUE, followTouchMove=TRUE, shared = FALSE,
          formatter = "#! function(){return this.point.x + '<br>' + this.point.pop + '<br>' + this.point.type + ': ' + this.point.y;} !#")
hp
```

[image]

In the above example using `hPlot()`, the additional variable `type` cannot be shown in tooltip because the array is not named.

In the example below using the same data, rather than using `hPlot()`, the plot is built up manually. Here the tooltips work because the array is named. The line starting `hm$series....` has `names=T`.

```
hm <- rCharts:::Highcharts$new()
dlev <- levels(d$type)
for(i in 1:length(dlev))
{
  hm$series(data = toJSONArray2(d[d$type==dlev[i],,drop=F], json = F,names=T), name = dlev[i],type = c("column"), marker = list(radius = 3))
}
hm$plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal", pointPadding = 0, groupPadding = 0, borderWidth = 0))
hm$tooltip(borderWidth=0, followPointer=TRUE, followTouchMove=TRUE, shared = FALSE,
          formatter = "#! function(){return this.point.x + '<br>' + this.point.pop + '<br>'+ this.point.type + ': ' + this.point.y;} !#")
hm
```

[image]